# X server for Windows

Tags: windows-7, cygwin, x11

I'm looking to run [Cygwin](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cygwin) [xterm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Xterm) on my machine. For this I need an X server, which one would you recommend?

It's important that it won't leak memory too much, and that it would be fast enough to allow reasonable terminal based work on the PC.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

How about [Cygwin/X](http://x.cygwin.com/)?

Comment: I see there are 2 alternatives Cygwin/X and Xming. Do you know which one is lighter in terms of cpu/memory consumption?

Comment: Xming is simple and easier to install though less configurable than Cygwin/X. It also has the advantage of more active development. On the other hand, Cygwin/X is much closer port of X for Windows with all the possible features.

Answer (score 2):

When I was on MS Windows XP, I found [Xming](http://sourceforge.net/projects/xming/) to be quite stable, manageable and not resource-hungry.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at [ciXwin](https://www.itefix.net/cixwin), a standalone solution packaging all Cygwin/X base stuff, fonts and ssh into a small and convenient installer (about 30 MB). **ciXwin** is designed for displaying remote clients via ssh. It is free for use and distribution under 2-sentence BSD license.

Disclaimer: I am the developer :-)